# Does eating a monk really make you immortal?

Tags: religion, mythology, journey-to-the-west

In *[Journey to the West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West)* demons and evil doers frequently capture the monk Xuanzang with the intent of eating him. They are said to believe that it will grant immortality and/or cleanse you of your most grievous sins.

However, on the surface it sure seems like bad karma to me: kidnapping, murder, eating meat...
But maybe monks fall into a special food category?

Comment: This seems like it might be a better fit for [Mythology SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

**Xuanzang is a special monk. He's a reincarnation of a "godly" being.**

---

> Along the journey, Xuanzang is constantly terrorised by monsters and demons because of a legend which says that one can attain immortality by consuming his flesh because he is a reincarnation of a holy being.
>
> <sub>Wikipedia - [*Journey to the West*, Xuanzang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuanzang_(Journey_to_the_West))</sub>

Basically, it's rumored that by eating Xuanzang, a reincarnated holy being's, flesh, demons themselves can become immortal.

#### Background information

**San Zang was originally Jin Chan Zi, Buddha's disciple.** He was banished to earth because he was disobedient, and didn't pay attention to Buddha's teachings. He was reincarnated as Mr. (Guang Rui) and Mrs. Chen's son.

(Different versions of stories follow, but to summarise:)

> Xuanzang was abandoned by his mother, after his father was killed by a man, who stole his identity and wife. The baby was set afloat in a river, and found by a priest, who later raised Xuanzang as a monk.
>
> Years after that, when Xuan Zang was all grown up, the Emperor of Great Tang asked him to hold a religious ceremony. On the ceremony, Xuan Zang was approached by the disguised Goddess of Mercy and her disciple. They gave him a monk's staff and robe and told him to fetch the scriptures from the Western Heavens.